# Regex - Capture only numbers that don't have a letter next to them

Tags: c#, regex

I have a task to create program that'll match digits without numbers infront of them.  For example:

> 6x^2+6x+6-57+8-9-90x

I'm trying to use Regex to capture all numbers with + or - before them - but without x afterwards.  I've tried

```
\[+-](\d+)[^x]
```

but it seems to capture the '-90' from '-90x' as well.

Comment: You know Regex serves as a template for matching a character pattern to the string that is being searched. Meaning that it's a Boolean function. I don't know what you mean by "capture".

Comment: I want it to only find numbers without x's so I can replace them.

Comment: does it capture the `'-90'` or juste the `'90'` from `'-90x'`? if first, that does not seem normal, if second, maybe it capures the last 'x' and not the first because there are others signs after '6x' so it matches the `^x`. It cannot match for '90x' because there are no other chars. I think the `[^x]` is wrong here

Comment: @yazanpro regex does contain the concept of a "capturing group", especially for use in search & replace.  So this does make sense.

Comment: @MarcL. -- yes it does.

Comment: You want to use regex to solve a problem? So now you have two problems!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct Regex would be this:

```
@"[+-]((?>\d+))(?!x)"
```

Alternative non- .NET solution:

```
[+-](\d++)(?!x)
```

---

```
@"
[+-]            // Prefix non captured
(               // Begin capturing group
    (?>         // Begin atomic (non-backtracking) group - this part is essential
        \d+     // One or more digits
    )           // End atomic group
)               // End capturing group
(?!             // Begin negative lookahead
    x           // 'x' literal
)               // End negative lookahead
"
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vsDwlB/2)

Comment: You are a Godsent.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained *why*, i.e. what the OP did wrong in his/her expression that failed.

Comment: That's great. +1 for the `Atomic Group` which I was looking for. But I would add some explanation of the Regex used.

Comment: It works because Atomic group disallows backtracking - thus, if element with x is found, it skips entire capture.

Comment: `@"[+-](\d++)(?!x)"` won't work in .NET as it does not support possessive quantifiers. Also, a link to regex101.com is not reliable when you want to prove a .NET regex works, as regex101.com does not support .NET regex flavor.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with the original regex is that the `[` is escaped and a literal `[` is thus matched, and another problem is with `(\d+)[^x]` that captures 1+ digits and captured into Group 1 and then a `[^x]` matches any char but `x`. It means it may also match a digit (as in your case, with `-90x`, the `[+-]` matches `-`,  `(\d+)` matches and captures `9` and `[^x]` matches `0`).

A more appropriate regex is to include a `\d` pattern with `x` into the negative lookahead:

```
[+-](\d+)(?![\dx])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%2b-%5d%28%5cd%2b%29%28%3f!%5b%5cdx%5d%29&i=6x%5e2%2b6x%2b6-57%2b8-9-90x).

**Pattern details**:

- `[+-]` - either `+` or `-`
- `(\d+)`  - Capturing group 1 matching 1 or more digits
- `(?![\dx])` - A negative lookahead that fails the match if 1+ digits are followed with a digit or `x`.